# JavaEE: Inject @Alteriative to Insance<Interface> with no default implementation

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I've got an ejb-JAR consistig of some Classes counting different values [Counter1, Counter2,...] all implementing the same Interface [ICountable]. Also part of this JAR is a class looping over all extisting counters and returning its values [CounterCollector].

Now I have two other WARs with the EJB packed into it.

My intention is to have the first WAR only using Counter1 and Counter3. The other WAR using Counter1 and Counter2. (The real scenario is a litte bit more complicated but I think it's enough information to get the idea)

I thougt of using @Alternative-Annotation on all Counters and having only the enabled Alternatives injected in CounterCollector as follows:

```
...

@Inject
private Instance<ICountable> counters;

public List<Integer> getCounts()
{
    List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ICountable countable : counters) {
         c.add(countable.count());
    }
    return c;
}

...
```

In WAR1 I activate counters 1 and 3 in the beans.xml:

```
<alternatives>
  <class>Counter1</class>
  <class>Counter3</class>
</alternatives>
```

in the second WARs beans.xml:

```
<alternatives>
  <class>Counter1</class>
  <class>Counter2</class>
</alternatives>
```

As long as the ICounter-implementations are NOT annotated as @Alternative everything works as expected (besides obviously all counters are triggert).

As soon as I annotate the ICounters with @Alternative they are not injected at all. No matter if they are enabled via beans.xml.

Isn't it possible to inject @Alternative-Annotated classes into javax.enterprise.inject.Instance?

Am I using the @Alternative in a way it is not ment to work or am I missing something?

Comment: I suspect the problem is the location of the beans.xml files that activate the alternatives. If the classes `Counter1`, `Counter2`, ... are located in jar1 and this has a META-INF/beans.xml, then this is responsible for activating the alternatives. The war1/beans.xml, war2/beans.xml do not have effect on the classes defined in jar1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is unrelated to `Instance<T>`, it's just about bean archives and selecting alternatives.

I suppose your WAR looks something like this:

```
WEB-INF/
    beans.xml
    classes/
    lib/
        ejb.jar
```

and `WEB-INF/beans.xml` is the place where you activate your alternatives.

Now it is important to note that `WEB-INF/classes` and `ejb.jar` are two distinct [bean archives](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#packaging_deployment_ee). Selecting an alternative via `beans.xml` only affects the bean archive containing this file.

So in your case, anything you do in `WEB-INF/beans.xml` will have no effect on `lib/ejb.jar`

You could try selecting your alternatives [at application level](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#declaring_selected_alternatives_application) using `@Priority` annotations on producer methods or on derived classes.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class Counter1SelectedForWar extends Counter1 { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I could have come up with that idea of subclassing by myself ;-)